# How to use Huawei EC156 modem on 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, huawei, usb-modem

How to configure Tata Photon+ USB Modem Huawei EC156 on Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat.
It is not getting detected in network manager nor in media. Is there any way out to configure and use internet with the modem on ubuntu 10.10 .

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/78164/configuring-tata-photon-usb-modem-huawei-ec156

Comment: how to make it work for 10.10

Comment: You can edit the original post.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    sudo apt-get install usb-modeswitch
```

These sticks come with a ZeroCD setup. When you first plug it it, you only see it as a pendrive for windows drivers. But the kernel already has the drivers, but not the information, that it needs a switch. This package solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no difference in 10.10
[Configuring Tata Photon + USB Modem Huawei EC156](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78164/configuring-tata-photon-usb-modem-huawei-ec156)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Imagine the linked site goes down for maintenance, or even forever: Your post would be useless to someone having the problem outlined here.