# data usages check option for DOCOM MF631 in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 3g

I connect my USB Modem DOCOMO MF631 in ubuntu 11.10 from the help of this site : [Configuring Tata Photon + USB Modem Huawei EC156](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78164/configuring-tata-photon-usb-modem-huawei-ec156). Now Ist problem is that i don't know my connection speedin ubuntu. In XP I can check my speed nearly 240 Kbps (2X). 2nd how to check remaining balance (data usages). xp mode docomo running setup allow check usages by *123# ( I'm using BSNL 3G SIM converted in 2G in DOCOMO Donggle) need help..........

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu you can check internet speed on System monitor ,
Gammu may can check your  balance amount ,

Comment: Thanks for ur reply........... but still i m not satisfied b'coz i m start using ubuntu last 3 day.. so all command or operation are unknown for me... so need more detail about "Gammu"